# Bundle doesn't want to install a gem (not yet checked out)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to run a Ruby on rails server, but a certain gem doesn't want to install. This rails program is not compatible with ruby 2.0, so I want to use ruby 1.9.3, which I installed, but I can't bundle install anymore...

```
$ bundle install
# ...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ bundle exec rails s
git://github.com/goodtouch/jbuilder.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
$ bundle show jbuilder
/Users/julien/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/jbuilder-7fb0eae924c7
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
```

In the `Gemfile`, I specified `ruby "1.9.3"`, then I ran `bundle install` again and got:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

The `Gemfile` line for this specific gem:

```
gem 'jbuilder', git: "git://github.com/goodtouch/jbuilder.git"
```

And what I get in the `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/goodtouch/jbuilder.git
  revision: 7fb0eae924c77318ede344f32a5c208b91cdbaac
  specs:
    jbuilder (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      blankslate (>= 2.1.2.4)
```

I really don't understand what's going on. I'm under Mac OS X.

Thank you.

Comment: you use `rvm`? run `ruby -v` and `rvm use 1.9.3` before  specified `ruby '1.9.3'` and `bundle install` i think you still use 2.0.0...

Comment: From bundler log have this /Users/julien/.bundler/ruby/`2.0.0`/jbuilder-7fb0eae924c7 this mean ruby version still 2.0.0

Comment: Yes I know, but I wonder where he finds this version of ruby... =°

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit**: You have to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to set ruby version. This is not set in the gem file. Ruby is not a gem.

This error might have one of many reasons.

From the [Bundler issues](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md)

```
# remove user-specific gems and git repos
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/bundler/ ~/.gems/cache/bundler/

# remove system-wide git repos and git checkouts
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/

# remove project-specific settings
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached gems and repos
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
rm -rf Gemfile.lock

# uninstall the rubygems-bundler and open_gem gems
rvm gemset use global # if using rvm
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler open_gem

# try to install one more time
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks, I used rbenv but apparently it didn't work, It's easier with `rvm` and it works ! Thanks !

Comment: Glad to help! I also prefer rvm. I think rvm is easier to wrap my head around. For the biggest differences between the two look at this. [Why rbenv?](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F)

Answer (score -1):

My issue was because my gemfile.lock was using the different

BUNDLED WITH

check the version and see if they match

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31755879)